# Running an application at startup in android

Tags: java, android, startup

I need run an android application at the startup. I have followed all the instructions concerning to permission in manifest file, created the BroadcastReceiver and added a dummy activity to the same Android project and run that activity manually at least once.
I have Turned the phone off and many times per day, the application starts properly always. The problem is that after three or four days, the application stops running at the phone boot and it is necessary again run manually
 the dummy activity once to extend its functionality for other three or four days.
Any kind of help is welcome.

Comment: On any Android device, you would need to run the activity after you initially install the app, and after the user presses "Force Stop" on the app's screen in Settings. Otherwise, you should be fine. Some devices do silly things and employ "Force Stop" behavior at other times, besides when the user taps that button. There is not a lot that you can do about this, other than yell at the device manufacturer.

Comment: Share some code

Answer (score 2):

Don't know which code you used, but I used this and it works fine always

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bibaswan: My code is exactly as you say. The application after be run manually once, remain working properly for three or four days. In That period I have restarted the phone many times and always the application starts without problems. But after  three or four days it does not start and it is necesary to runs it manually for extending its functionality for another similar time period.

Comment: I think android system reduces its priority when you don't open the app for some days. You have to use the app once in a while

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 3.1, your app is first in a "stopped" state(and it is different from `onStop()`). In stopped state, your manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` will not work. You will have to run your app after installing it at least once to make it work.

Also, you should not Force Stop your app as Commonsware pointed out. Force Stopping will terminate the app process.

Comment: Id did what you say but the app. stops after three or four days.

Comment: So, you must be using `BOOT_COMPLETED` to run activity on startup. Right?? And after 3-4 days, when it stops working does it show any error message or it just does not run at startup?

Comment: What device are you using?